# Use variable to store "change.doc" path

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use variable as a firestore doc path :

```
        console.log(change.doc.data().m_1.name);   <----- This work well !

        a = 1;
        let me = change.doc.data().m_+a;    <----- But not that....
        console.log(me.name);
```

How can i do that ? 
Thank you in advance ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use brackets when using dynamic property.

```
let me = change.doc.data()['m_' + a];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to build the name of the key as its own variable and use that to index into the object.

```
const a = 1;
const key = "m_" + a;
const me = change.doc.data()[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use your `a` variable in your example you're asking JS to add the number 1 to your functions output. This is not the correct way. You want to use a key to access the data from your `data()` functions return output as shown below.

```
change = {
doc: {
    data: function() {
      return {
        m_1: {
          name: "Mario",
          occupation: "plumber",
          siblings: 1,
          age: 24
        },
        m_2: {
          name: "Mike",
          occupation: "developer",
          siblings: 3,
          age: "28"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log("Old way:" + change.doc.data().m_1.name);

const a = 1;
let me = change.doc.data()['m_' + a];
console.log("Desired way: " + me.name)
```

I have assumed a simple data structure derived from your question but I am not certain that it's what you get. But it might look a little like it.

**EDIT** awww.... The page didn't refresh and I did not see the two first answers :( well... at least we agree